# Cannot validate email in shiny

Tags: r, rstudio, shiny, shiny-server

I used the following code to validate the **email address** in shiny app, but it seems that it does not apply.

I have uploaded it to the shiny server and maybe you can try to type anything in the email column.

https://brianzhang1994.shinyapps.io/Anqi/

Whatever you type in, it does not report error.

ui.R:

```
library(shiny)
shinyUI(fluidPage(
titlePanel("Please Enter Your Info"),
sidebarLayout(
sidebarPanel(
  textInput("firstname","First Name:"),
  textInput("lastname","Last Name:"),
  dateInput("dob","Date of Birth:",format = "mm-dd-yyyy"),
  textInput("numbers","Cell Phone Numers (10 digits):",value = 1111111111),
  textInput("email","Email Address:")
),

mainPanel(
   dataTableOutput("tableforpatient")
)
)
))
```

server.R:

```
library(shiny)
isValidEmail <- function(x) {
grepl("\\<[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Z]{2,}\\>", as.character(x), 
ignore.case=TRUE)
}

shinyServer(function(input, output) {

output$tableforpatient <- renderDataTable({
validate(
  need(input$firstname !="", 
       paste("First Name: Please Input your firstname")),
  need(input$lastname !="", 
       paste("Last Name: Please Input your lastname")),
  need(nchar(as.numeric(input$numbers)) == 10 , 
       paste("Cell Phone Numers: Please Input a 10-digit-number only"),
  need(isValidEmail(input$email),
       paste("Email Address: Please Input a valid E-mail address"))
       )
)
patient <- data.frame(firstname=input$firstname,
                      lastname=input$lastname,
                      dob=input$dob,
                      number=paste0("+1",input$numbers),
                      email=input$email)
})
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to close the bracket of your "need cell phone numbers" `need()` function:

```
need(nchar(as.numeric(input$numbers)) == 10 , 
       paste("Cell Phone Numbers: Please Input a 10-digit-number only")),
need(isValidEmail(input$email),
       paste("Email Address: Please Input a valid E-mail address"))
```

Comment: Thank you sooo much. R didn't report any errors so I did not find I forgot to close it.... It works well now!